# Where is Objects tab in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode6

I am following a hello world tutorial for xcode. I opened my LaunchScreen.xib file in Xcode6, here is how it looks like:

[image]

But according to the tutorial, there needs to be an Objects tab. Can anyone tell me where i can find it?

Thanks

Edit: Here is how it looks like in the tutorial:

[image]

I want to find my AppDelegate.h file but i cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Objects section of the document outline has been removed. Everything that was formerly under it is now a top-level item in the document outline. So everything that you now see in the outline that isn't under the “Placeholders” section would formerly have been under “Objects”.

Xcode's project templates have changed since your tutorial was written.  When your tutorial was written, the template used a xib file that contained the app delegate and the window. Now, the template uses a storyboard. The system instantiates the app delegate and the window automatically and loads the initial view controller and its view from the storyboard.

The xib you are looking at (`LaunchScreen.xib`) is a new feature for iOS 8 that replaces the launch image PNGs you must use in older versions of iOS.  It is **not** the xib you are looking for to work through your tutorial.

It would be possible to modify your project to match what the tutorial assumes you have, but doing so is probably not worth the effort. Look for a tutorial written for Xcode 5.1 or later that assumes you are starting with a storyboard.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like i need to find more recent tutorials